# jquery repeater layout horizontal To view Items Like youtube

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jtable, repeater

I need jquery repeater with  horizontal layout to be able to bind data from database by returning it in json format or any needed format by and be able to use paging . some thing like jtable but horizontal layout . i want layout like youtube home page layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was needed to view multiple videos record from database  inline like YouTube view videos in home page  plus paging  ..my project use Web API and jquery and view list using jtable(
 http://jtable.org /) and i wasn't able to view my video as i want but now i can using the following

**in Web APi controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public object GettAllVideosBypaging(object parmter)
    {

        dynamic Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(parmter.ToString());
        int jtStartIndex = Result.jtStartIndex;
        int jtPageSize = Result.jtPageSize;
        //string jtSorting = Result.jtSorting;

        try
        {
            List<PublicTrainingVideos> lst = trnmanager.GetAllVideos(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize).ToList();
            return new { Result = "OK", Records = lst, TotalRecordCount = trnmanager.GetVideosRecordsCount() };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
        }}
```

**In jsFile (i for now i just view video name but i can inside li draw any html ) **

```
function GetPublicVideos() {    
jqueryNew('#TaskCommentsTableContainer').jtable({
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 2,
    sorting: false,
    defaultSorting: 'VideoID ASC',
    actions: {
        listAction: '/Videos/GettAllVideosBypaging'
    },
    fields: {
        VideoID: {
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false

        } ,
        ShowData: {
            width: '20%',
            display: function (data) {
                var VidePhoto = data.record.VideoName;
                return $('<li  style="display:inline"">' + VidePhoto + '</li>');
            }
        }

  }

});
jqueryNew('#TaskCommentsTableContainer').jtable('load');}
```

in User controller

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/js/PublicTrainingVideos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetPublicVideos();

});
</script>
 <div class="comments">
    <ul>
        <div id="TaskCommentsTableContainer"></div>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**In Style Sheet (all i need to just custom the style to view inline)**

```
#TaskCommentsTableContainer table {
display: block;position:relative;
width:  500px;}
#TaskCommentsTableContainer table tbody{ 
display: block;
position:relative;width:100%; min-height: 23px;}
#TaskCommentsTableContainer table tr{
  display: block;
  position:relative;width:20%;float:right}
```